# SQL Server Merge Replication Problems

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I have Merge replication setup on a CRM system. Sales reps data merges when they connect to the network (I think when SQL detects the notebooks are connected), and then they take the laptops away and merge again when they come back (there are about 6 laptops in total merging via 1 server).

This system seems fine when initially setup, but then it almost grinds to a halt after about a month passes, with the merge job taking nearly 2 hours to run, per user, the server is not struggling in any way.

If I delete the whole publication and recreate all the subscriptions it seems to work fine until about another month passes, then I am back to the same problem.

The database is poorly designed with a lack of primary keys/indexes etc, but the largest table only has about 3000 rows in it.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and if there is a risk of losing data when deleting and recreating the publication?

Comment: How often do the users sync? Are there reports or admin that write data they run monthly ?

Comment: Some user sync daily as there pcs are on the network all the time about 70%, and a couple only have there laptops on the network a couple of times, or once a week for a short period of time, about an hour or two. If there is or more info anyone needs please post a commennt.

Comment: There is nothing that runs on a monthly basis, just checked the last sync took 5.5 hours done overnight last night

Comment: I have noticed a frequent message in replication monitor:

Waiting 60 seconds before polling for further changes

Any idea why it is waiting this long? or if I can change the setting?

Comment: It seems the problem here is the buildup of metadata. 

If I set the retention period to say 14 days (currently never expires), does anyone know, if one of the sales reps comes back after that period, will the changes they have made be lost? Or will they get picked up when the subscription re-initialises

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the metadata created by sql server replication, there is an overnight job that emptys and refills a 3000 row table. This causes replication to replicate all of these rows each day.

The subscriptions were set to never expire which means the old meta data was never being deleted by sql server.

I have set the subscription period to 7 days now in the hope tat it will now clean up the meta data after this period. I did some testing and proved that changes were not lost if a subscription expired. But any updates on the server took priority over the client.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered with "Waiting 60 second(s) before polling for further changes" recently in 2008 R2.

Replication monitor shows "In progress state" for replication but only step 1 (Initialization) and step 2 (Schema changes and bulk inserts) were performed. 
I was very puzzled why other steps do not executed?

The reason was simple - it seems that for merge replication demands tcp/ip (and or not sure) named pipes protocols activation.

No errors were reported.

Probably the similar problem (some sort of connection problem) became apparent in Ryan Stephens case.